# What reasons could make psycopg2 mismatch a ca cert that datagrip accepts?

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate, python-3.7, certbot

I want to make a python application that connects directly to the database. I got it to work with ssl required, but setting it to verify CA the connection fails. In datagrip, I checked the 'use ssl' box and pointed the CA file to the same one python was using and it worked flawlessly. I even edited the CA and changed a character to ensure the connection would fail, and edited the character back and watched the connection succeed. I've also tried pg_isready and it's failing. I do all this testing on my pc with the database on another computer on my network. The other computer is running Debian 11, and doesn't seem to have any firewall, and I've tried allowing all my programs through Window's firewall. I think the errors might lay in my configuration, however I'm really unsure since datagrip is working.

Here's the failing part

```
 try:
        # Create a SQLAlchemy engine
        engine = create_engine(DB_URL, connect_args={
            #"sslmode": "require",
            "sslmode": "verify-ca",
            "sslrootcert": "chain.pem"
        })

.........
```

It works fine on sslmode. I also tried in raw psycopg2 and it failed the same way.

Despite setting --timeout=5 pg_isready practically instantly gives me this

```
192.168.1.69:5432 - no response
```

Here's my psycopg2 python

```
db_params = {
    "dbname": "db",
    "user": "db_user",
    "password": "db_pwd",
    "host": "192.168.1.69",
    "port": "5432",
    "sslmode": "verify-ca",
    "sslrootcert": "chain.pem"  # Path to the CA certificate file
}
connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
```

Here's the result from the above code

```
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing psycopg 2.9.7 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
[9104] psycopgmodule: configuring libpq libcrypto callbacks 
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing module constants
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing module types
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing datetime module
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing encodings table
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing adapters
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing basic exceptions
[9104] psycopgmodule: initializing sqlstate exceptions
[9104] psycopgmodule: module initialization complete
['bolt']
[9104] psyco_connect: dsn = 'dbname=db user=db_user password=pw host=192.168.1.69 port=5432 sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=chain.pem', async = 0
[9104] connection_setup: init connection object at 000001944844E908, async 0, refcnt = 1
[9104] con_connect: connecting in SYNC mode
[9104] conn_connect: new PG connection at 0000019447A4AF30
[9104] conn_connect: PQconnectdb(dbname=db user=db_user password=pw host=192.168.1.69 port=5432 sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=chain.pem) returned BAD
[9104] connection_init: FAILED
[9104] conn_close: PQfinish called
[9104] connection_dealloc: deleted connection object at 000001944844E908, refcnt = 0
```

Bolt was a debug statement in my code for the user input of the query, not a part of psycopg2 connection.

Here's what my sqlalchemy spits out

```
postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@localhost/dbname -> postgresql+psycopg2://database_postgres_user:password@192.168.1.69:5432/table
[28112] psyco_connect: dsn = 'host=192.168.1.69 dbname=database user=database_postgres_user password=password port=5432 sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=chain.pem', async = 0
[28112] connection_setup: init connection object at 000001E95A3956D8, async 0, refcnt = 1
[28112] con_connect: connecting in SYNC mode
[28112] conn_connect: new PG connection at 000001E959645310
[28112] conn_connect: PQconnectdb(host=192.168.1.69 dbname=database user=database_postgres_user password=password port=5432 sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=chain.pem) returned BAD
[28112] connection_init: FAILED
[28112] conn_close: PQfinish called
[28112] connection_dealloc: deleted connection object at 000001E95A3956D8, refcnt = 0
(psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "192.168.1.69", port 5432 failed: SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

And I tried pg8000 that gave a similar result

Here's my certbot renewal hook

```
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/fullchain.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/privkey.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/privkey.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/cert.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/cert.pem
chown postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/fullchain.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/privkey.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/cert.pem
chmod 700 /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/fullchain.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/privkey.pem /etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/cert.pem
```

Here's my pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

# MY CUSTOM STUFF
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

And here's some relevant stuff from postgresql.conf

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
listen_addresses = '*'
# comma-separated list of addresses;
# defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
# (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
# - SSL -
ssl = on
#ssl_ca_file = ''
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/fullchain.pem'
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/cert.pem'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
ssl_key_file = '/etc/postgresql/13/main/cert_copies/privkey.pem'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
```

Here's the error in postgres log

```
2023-08-18 16:29:31.483 PDT [5913] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does chain.pem come from?

Comment: What error is in the db server's log file?  This sometimes gives better info than what the client gets.

Comment: SQL alchemy is too complicated to debug with.  Could you show the actual code and error when using raw psycopg2?

Comment: @jjanes I put the error in the /var/log/...... in the post, and the actual code when using psycopg2.

Comment: @jjanes  I was reading from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBQ-SSL-CERTIFICATES  It's saying about root and leaf certificates and direction will matter, as in the server can verify the client or vice versa or perhaps both. I'm really unsure what a leaf cert is or what certbot/letsencrypt has provided me. Could this be my problem? I just copy pasted the fullchain.pem (renamed chain.pem)